# Stop Finder from buffering (network) videos in macOS (Sierra)

Tags: video, vpn, network-shares, finder, macos-sierra

I'm using a VPN connection to my movie database at home.
Unfortunately when I open it in Finder and click on a movie (mkv), before I can even open it or drag it somewhere, the bouncy ball comes into play. Watching the incoming data stream I see how it starts streaming content to the Finder. This is pretty meaningless to me, I guess it tries to generate a Preview.
This is very annoying for network files, as when they are big it takes forever. Is there a way to disable this behavior (especially for the network files)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do this right down the hierarchy if some prefs have already been set

- Select your folder
- View menu > Show View Options  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>
- Un-check Show icon Preview

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped with the spinning ball!!! I still see a lot of traffic happening in the background, but never the less this an excellent solution!